# Find the curve of the maximum value of work done?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

Suppose $C$ is a simple close curve (i.e. it doesn’t intersect itself) in the first quadrant. If $F = (y^2/2 + x^2y, -x^2 + 8x)$, find the curve that produces the maximum amount of work done by $F$.
What is the maximum value of work?

Comment: Have you looked up 'calculus of variations', or are you having trouble applying it?

Comment: I have no idea what that means but it is probably beyond what I have learnt. All we did was Green and Stokes theorem

Comment: Without the assumption that the curve is positively oriented, the maximal work is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

The maximization problem can be reduced to the case of a region in the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by using Green's Theorem:
$$ \oint_C F\cdot ds=\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dA.$$
So, we can maximize the integral over $D$ of 
$$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=-2x+8-(y+x^2).$$
This is achieved precisely by integrating over the entirety of the region $D$ on which the integrand above is non-negative:
$$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 8-2x-y-x^2\ge 0,\text{and}\:x,y\ge 0\}.$$
So, we need to figure out which points in the first quadrant have $y\le 8-2x-x^2$. Completing the square yields $y-9\le -1-2x-x^2=-(x^2+2x+1)=-(x+1)^2.$ So, 
$$ D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\le -(x-1)^2+9\}.$$
We see that $D$ is bounded by a parabola opening in the negative $y$ direction and the coordinate axes. So, the boundary curve $C=\partial D$ is given by parametrizing the union 
$$\underbrace{\{(0,t):0\le t\le8\}}_{\text{the portion of the $y-$axis}}\cup\underbrace{\{(t,0): 0\le t\le 4\}}_{\text{the portion of the $x-$axis}}\cup\underbrace{\{(x,y):y=-(x-1)^2+9,\text{and}\:0\le x\le 4\}}_{\text{the portion of the curve}}.$$
At this point, you should compute 
$$ \oint_{\partial D} F\cdot ds=\iint_{D}(-2x+8-y-x^2)dA$$
as this maximizes the work (i.e. the line integral on the left).

Comment: After this, how do I find the maximum work

Comment: From here you should just compute the integral. I'll add that.

Comment: I dont know if I made a dumb mistake, but I got a negative number?

Comment: This should not result in a negative number, because $D$ is nonempty and the integrand is non-negative on $D$ (and actually strictly positive in some places).